# Check if one picklist value is selected then other picklist value does not contain that value again

Tags: validation, admin

Consider 2 picklists

1st picklist contain values : abc,xyz, pqr.

2nd picklist contain values : abc, xyz, pqr

So if 1st picklist is selected with value "abc" then on select on 2nd picklist it should not contain value "abc". 2nd picklist should show only two values "xyz","pqr".

How can it be done using validation rule ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63244/discussion-on-question-by-chetan-check-if-one-picklist-value-is-selected-then-ot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to restrict visibility on the picklist values through a validation rule. However, you can create a validation rule that does not allow you to save the record when the picklist values are the same.

What you'll want to do is create a formula that checks the value of the first picklist and the value of the second picklist. If those are the same, then the validation rule will throw an error.

IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(picklist_1__c, 'abc'), (ISPICKVAL(picklist_2__c, 'abc'))

Here is some more information from SFDC on formula operators:https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US